# Alphabetize rows without losing data

Tags: google-sheets, rows, alphabetical-sort

My sheet contains volunteer data imported via query from another worksheet. I'm assigning various roles to each volunteer on this sheet.

I'd like to alphabetize by last name to make it easier to locate names. But I need to be able to add names to the "Roster" while keeping the assignments with the correct names.

In my current setup, when I alphabetize, inserting a new name causes misalignment of assignments. Any ideas how I can avoid this?

Here's a test sheet to demo the process. The actual sheet contains dozens of volunteers and multiple data columns for each volunteer.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KqXRYda9Z0dGJfEACfPMAAtdN1re02-1H0Bmrn9aF58/edit#gid=0

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome new user, as I understand it you'd ask this on a different site (possibly Superuser ?)

Comment: sheet is private

Comment: What you are asking is not possible directly, you could make an VLOOKUP column and on a separate sheet make key-value pairs. Dropdown wit the name and next to it the role. Then you can VLOOKUP the role based on name.

Comment: Sorry I gave a private link. Here's the public version: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KqXRYda9Z0dGJfEACfPMAAtdN1re02-1H0Bmrn9aF58/edit?usp=sharing